# Exception during Callable execution

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, future

I have the following Callable:

```
public class Worker implements Callable<Boolean>{

   @Override
   public Boolean call(){
      boolean success=true;

      //do Something
     return success;
   }

}
```

Now I'm executing it:

```
Worker worker - new Worker();
Future<Boolean> submit = executor.submit(worker);
```

I'm storing the submit in kind of hashMap for some operation to be performed somewhere in code.

How can I know if any exception has occured in `worker.call()` function?

Will `submit.isCancelled()` return true if some sort of Exception occurred and false if everything works ok?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call [`Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) it will throw your exception wrapped in a [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html).

Comment: but Future.get will return boolean? can you please post some code?

Comment: It won't return, it will `throw` the exception.

Comment: `V call() throws Exception` is original declaration of Callable.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), `Future<V>` will re-throw the exception that occurred during `.call()` (though wrapped in an `ExecutionException`), and `isCancelled()` would still be false in this case.

Answer (score 5):

In [Guava Librairies](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html), there is a `FutureCallback` interface which has a `onFailure(Throwable t)` method which should interest you

Adding Google Guava Librairies to a project is never a waste of space :-)

Comment: Never a waste of space unless you're very tight on space.

Answer (score 2):

*submit.get()* will throw an *ExecutionException*