# How to handle exception from Callable<Void>

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I would like to know how to handle exceptions from my Callable when I use Void as a return type.

Something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            call a third party code where an exception is thrown...
            return null;
        }

});
```

Since I don't need any result from this callable I don't call get() on the Future returned from calling executor.submit(). Thus the exception is swallowed.

What is the right way to handle such exceptions?

Comment: Your code looks fishy to me. You can't even return null if you mention void as return type of the method

Comment: Actually, you can return null as long as the type is not primitive :)

Comment: Sorry ..was that capital V?

Comment: Yes, it's Void, not void :)

Comment: @user3505725 the big Void is used to hold the Void.Type which is void.class

Comment: @user3505725 You cannot parameterize a type with `void`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417903/exception-during-callable-execution  => `Future.get` IS the right way ;)

Comment: @Mik378 That's a blocking call and defeats OP's purpose not to have blocking.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Nothing in the OP evokes the issue of blocking call.

Comment: @Mik378 It is implicit in using an executor service in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about try/catch within your call() method? - I suppose it depends on what you want to do if an exception occurs.

```
public Void call() throws Exception {
    try {
        ThirdParty.doSomething();
    } catch(SomeTypeException e) {
        SomeErrorHandler.handleThisError(e); // E.g. report it to the user
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I just need to push the exception up in calling stack. Our application catches all runtime exceptions and shows a dialog for the user.

Comment: @Behnil That's obviously impossible for a task you fork off to another thread. That thread has its own call stack, where at the top is a call to your submitted task. There is no exception handler there if you don't put it in.

Comment: It won't appear on the same stack, as it is executed on the thread of the Executor.